# JDBC SQL Server: Row doesn't appear after insert

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, insert

I'm trying to insert rows on SQL Server using a JDBC driver.

The query works on SQL Server and I can see the row.

However, in my code, I don't get any error but the row doesn't appear.

What is even weirder, my auto-increment field is incremented, i.e. let's say my auto-increment field has value 3, I run my code, nothing appears. I run the query on SQLServer, the new row has value 5.

```
    String query = "insert into SSSI_ADMIN.NBSIUSER(UserName,UserDomain) values('test4','domain4')";
    Statement stmnt = null;

    String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://dt112654:1433;databaseName=SIBD;user=u;password=*****";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);


        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmnt = conn.createStatement();

        stmnt.execute(query);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if ( stmnt != null)
        {
            stmnt.close();
        }
    }
```

Regards,
Nuno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not committing your change.

You have to call `conn.commit()` after `stmnt.execute(query);`

Comment: or he can simply remove `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 that wouldn't be recommended as one wouldn't be able to rollback then,if required.

Comment: @LiuYan刘研: true. Although I consider using autocommit a "hack". What's the use of a transactional database if you "disable" transactions ;)

Comment: lol, don't laugh at me, i did a lots auto commit operations on transactional database.

Answer (score 1):

because this is code "conn.setAutoCommit(false);"；one way to do this is "conn.setAutoCommit(true)" or delete this code "conn.setAutoCommit"; the other way to do this is after you execute the query you should add the another code "conn.commit()".